# Passing JSON to JsonResult not working while passing JSON object nor JSON.stringify

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this class in my project:
[image]

I made a JsonResult method in controller which has as parameter an object from this class:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult NewAreaCode(AreaCode model)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am trying to call this method in an Ajax request, I tried in two ways:

```
var areaCode = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#City_idCity").attr("value");
var City_idCity = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#areaCode").attr("value");
var model = JSON.stringify({ "idAreaCode": "0", "areaCode": areaCode, "City_idCity": City_idCity });
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Address/NewAreaCode',
    data: model,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

```
function submitNewAreaCode(dataContent) {
var areaCode = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#City_idCity").attr("value");
var City_idCity = $(dataContent).parent().parent().find("#areaCode").attr("value");
var model = { "idAreaCode": "0", "areaCode": areaCode, "City_idCity": City_idCity };
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Address/NewAreaCode',
    data: model,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

}

But I can't call the JSON method.

In the first case, using JSON.stringify, I got the error that cannot convert Int32 to String.
In the second case, passing object directly, I got the error "Invalid JSON primitive: idAreaCode" (or any of first parameter passed, it doesn't matter).

I don't understand what's happening, because I made something similar in another case, but with a different class:
[image]

I created a similar situation, changing the parameter of AreaCode to Country, I called the Ajax request with code below:

```
function editCountrySubmit(element) {
element = $(element).parent();
var divCountry = "#" + $(element).attr("id");
var div = $(divCountry).html();
var idCountry = divCountry.substring(divCountry.indexOf("-") + 1, divCountry.length);
var country = $(divCountry + " #countryName").attr("value");
var countryCode = $(divCountry + " #countryCode").attr("value");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Address/EditCountry",
    data: { "idCountry": idCountry, "country": country, "countryCode": countryCode },
    success: function (data) {
        updateCountryList(data, element);
    }
});}
```

And with this, the code worked.

Am I forgetting something? Or there is a problem with my class? Remembering that no one of attributes accepts NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you're attempting to put a `string` representation of zero ("0") into a model property called `idAreaCode`, which happens to be of type `int`:

```
var model = JSON.stringify({ "idAreaCode": "0", "areaCode": areaCode, "City_idCity": City_idCity });
```

Try this instead:

```
var model = JSON.stringify({ "idAreaCode": 0, "areaCode": areaCode, "City_idCity": City_idCity });
```

Comment: I forgot telling, I already tried it, the result is the same: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."